# Script to spawn a list of commands up to n% of CPU utilization and/or m% of memory consumption

Tags: linux, windows, parallel-processing, cpu-usage, scheduler

I am looking for a script that will spawn each command in a list until CPU/memory/network reaches a specified bound.

Some commercial scheduling tools will run as many jobs as it can until CPU utilization hits 90%. At that point, they wait until CPU utilization goes below a specified point and start another job. This maximizes utilization to finish the set faster.

An obvious example is in copying files. With 100+ files to copy, it is ludicrous to copy them one at a time. Such little CPU time is used, there should be many copies started. I/O bandwidth and network bandwidth become the constraint to manage.

I would like to not reinvent the wheel if there is already something available. Anyone know of something like this?

Comment: `man xargs`, search for `--max-procs=`. There are many questions here related to xargs usage, and I think they will be of help to you. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - This is a good suggestion. It still leaves two outstanding issues; knowing the CPU/memory/bandwidth utilization and it is not available on Windows.

Comment: If you have a production-level problem, you'll have to decide which is better: to build or buy. IMHO, A cross-platform solution really begs for a commercial solution. Maybe there is an open-source equivalent, but any solution will take time to get working right. Seems like a project-mgmt's 3-legged stool: time, resources, features (and quality!) applies to this problem. Good luck finding the right tool. Oh yeah, You'll want to use OS tags, for more readership on your question. Note the relatively low follower counts on the ones you are using.